# Is it possible for regression model to predict patterns separately from data has multiple patterns?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model

I want to predict sold number of each drink(hot and cold) without clustering.

I have data which contains sold number of hot and cold drinks.

I trained it with linear model in scikit, and I thought I can predict the sold number which is different shape based on it's hot or cold.

But I got one **very horizontal(average?)** line.
The prediction result are all the same no matter I predict hot or cold drinks.

**Experiments:**

**Expected result:** I can predict pattern of each hot or cold drink.

**Train X:** hot or cold, drink ID, date, week, day(ex:0 for Mon., 6 for Sun.), month.

**Train y:** sold numbers of 6 drinks in a month has 28 days.

Fig. of train data:

x -> days ex:1,2...28, y -> sold numbers
[image]

Fig. when I trained with sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression:

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(train_X, train_y)
```

[image]

Fig. when I trained with sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet:

```
model = linear_model.ElasticNet(max_iter=100).fit(train_X, train_y)
```

[image]

I tried linear_model but it seems only to predict a "average" results.

So linear model only can predict **one pattern(trend)** of data even if I combine all patterns in a dataset?

So maybe all regression models can only predict one pattern(trend) of data? or other regression model can reach that ?

Comment: Hi, my dear slavic friend! Are you talking about linear regression or any kind of regression?

Comment: @code_worker could you provide more details about your data and your used method  (some code and a table and/or graph for instance). It is not so clear why you do not get the trend that you expect. Possibly you specify the model incorrectly.

Comment: @asdf yes, linear regression and elasticnet.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I update it some figures to explain

Comment: What were your expectations for these graphs/data? In your graphs, I do not see a strong rise or decline in the number of sold numbers of drinks as a function of time (is it days on the x-axis?). So the fitted curve (when it is a straight line) will be flat and resemble something close to the average.

Comment: What is represented on the x-axis and y-axis of your graphs?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings x is the day, y for sold numbers.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings . Right, the trend is not clear. So I try figure out one way to predict sold numbers of each drinks of each day, firstly I think about regression model.

Comment: @code_worker So what is the question about statistics?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I don't know if there's a term to describe what I want. I have 6 sold numbers of 6 drinks, and I want model to predict(or seperate?) 6 patterns from the Fig. of train data

Comment: @code_worker what are you doing this analysis for? Is it a hypothetical study question, or is there a practical reason (e.g. is it for work)? Why do you have these data? How did you get the data? What do you think/hope you want to achieve? Etc. If you describe these things in common language, rather then trying to seek for statistical terms that you do not understand or know anyway, then it might be easier for others to help to formulate a good statistical question out of it.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I fix the title and the context. thx

Answer (score 2):

Linear regression can predict different patterns of data - you can use splines, you can use polynomial terms and so on.  In addition, there is the whole field of time series analysis, although that usually deals with cases where there are more time points than you seem to have.

But the problem seems to be that your data have no pattern. Thus, when regression (of any sort) or any other method comes up with a flat line, it is doing what it should - saying that there is no pattern in your data.

If you had some *a priori* reason to expect a pattern, then you have learned something: Your reason is incorrect, at least in this data set without any covariates.

However, since it seems like you are trying to predict the sales of drinks, I'm puzzled as to why you have no covariates in your model.  Certainly the temperature and whether it is a weekend ought to be included.

Comment: I know maybe I lose some important covariates like weather, temperature. What I want to know is model to predict(or seperate?) 6 patterns from the Fig. of train data. But I don't know is that possible or some term to describe the goal. thx